# Class handle. Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I have 2 similar classes:

```
classdef class1 < handle

    properties (Access = public)
        b
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        a
    end

    methods (Access = public)
        function this = class1()
            this.a = 1;
            this.b = 1;
        end

        function test(this)
            'Inside class'
            this.a
            this.b
            this.a = 2;
            this.b = 2;
        end
    end

end
```

And the second:

```
classdef class2

    properties (Access = public)
        b
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        a
    end

    methods (Access = public)
        function this = class2()
            this.a = 1;
            this.b = 1;
        end

        function test(this)
            'Inside class'
            this.a
            this.b
            this.a = 2;
            this.b = 2;
        end
    end

end
```

One time I inherit from handle. Other one I don't do it. After I create such script:

```
solver1 = class1();
solver1.b
solver1
solver1.test()
solver1.b
solver1
solver1.test()



solver2 = class2();
solver2.b
solver2
solver2.test()
solver2.b
solver2
solver2.test()
```

If I debug my program step by step, I see that ***a*** and ***b*** haven't changed in the second class after `solver2.test()`. But the first class these variable have changed after `solver1.test()`. What resasons this issue?

Comment: It's a feature of the [handle class](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html) you inherit the first class from.

Comment: I understand it. What do handle class?

Comment: One moment. I read again it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with next way. I declare global variable into class. And after this, I can check this any variable in and out class. This is bad way, but it's work.